# Is there any FOIA-like law or process by which a federal agency would sign or otherwise authenticate the documents they issue?

Tags: us-federal-government, notaries

A friend of mine needs to get a federal document authenticated for a legal case in a foreign court. The first part of the authentication process requires that the document be signed or bear the seal of the agency that issued it. The [document my friend needs](https://www.deadiversion.usdoj.gov/drug_chem_info/oxycodone/oxycodone.pdf) is neither signed nor bears any seal.

**Is there any FOIA-like law or process by which federal agencies would sign or otherwise authenticate the documents they issue?**

---

**Addendum**: As correctly noted in the comments, the authentication process *will* involve the department of state at some point. The issue here is that for the document to be authenticated by the DoS, the document:

> Must include a legible signature of the official's name, printed name and title, and seal of the agency

*‒ [Source](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/records-and-authentications/authenticate-your-document/authentication-certificate-requirements.html) - under "Authentication certificates"*

This question asks about any laws or process that would allow my friend to satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Just curious: how would that document, the statements it contains, or the fact that the US government published it, be useful in a court proceeding?  It's just general information about oxycodone, and doesn't seem likely to bear on the facts of any case.

Comment: I would guess this would go through the [State Department Office of Authorizations](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/records-and-authentications/authenticate-your-document/office-of-authentications.html), but it's not clear from the web site how it applies to this particular document.

Comment: @NateEldredge’s question is possibly relevant here. Depending on what info you need, there may be another document that would be a better choice to authenticate the info. For instance, if you need “oxycodone is Schedule II in the United States,” you might want to look for the actual law or regulation listing it instead of a fact sheet.

Comment: @NateEldredge This information was requested by the lawyer handling the case to establish the existence and legitimacy of this medication in the country where it was prescribed because oxycodone is not recognized in the country where my friend was detained.

Comment: I think at this point, it is not about law but about State Department procedure.  If you don't get an answer here, I would see if you can contact the Office of Authorizations and ask.

Comment: I also found https://www.govinfo.gov/about/authentication from the GPO suggesting that at least some documents are distributed as digitally signed PDFs.  That file doesn't seem to be signed, but maybe you can find some other document with similar content that is.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I only found 2 documents that discuss what Oxycodone is, and only one of them satisfied all the points that need to be established. I think you're right in that there is no law that governs this subject. I will try to find other ways to get my friend the documents he needs. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Most agencies offer certified copies of documents. But it depends to some extent upon the nature of the document. In principle, any competent adult can certify the authenticity of a document.